# When using TortoiseSVN, is there a way to highlight a deeply nested new file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For example, I might have added a new file several folders down in the folder structure. If the only change to the project is the addition of the file, the icons in Windows Explorer show the green ticks. Is there a way to show a different icon to highlight that a new file exists somewhere, which may need adding to svn?

Comment: Forgot to ask: what do you mean by "added a new file": Simply created the file, or created and added it to subversion (i.e. with TortoiseSVN/Add command)?

Comment: In my experience (and because I'm very impatient) I don't trust the shell overlays. Yes, they update eventually, but I issue a `Check for modifications` at the root of my checkout and I know immediately if it is dirty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open TortoiseSVN Setting
- Navigate to `Icon Overlays`
- Check `Unversioned files mark parent folder as modified` and click on OK button

[image: TortoiSVN Setting]
I'm testing on version 1.8 but I still can see this option on 1.7.12!

Comment: Perfect. I went through the settings before asking the question to try to avoid looking a fool! However, I failed to find this (and to not look like a fool). Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Shell overlays (green/red/etc. ticks) do not update immediately. If you wait enough, you will eventually get a modified (red) tick all the way back to the root of your working copy. You can also issue the [Clean up] command which includes the [Refresh shell overlays] option for faster update.

That being said the [Check for modifications] command is still the only reliable way to see if a working copy is dirty or not.

Comment: It never seems to get a change in icon, even after a reboot or a clean up operation. It does come up when checking for modifications. Problem is that I've quite a few repositories that I update from several machines and I keep catching myself forgetting to check in new files because there's no indication.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of TSVN? I tested with TortoiseSVN 1.8.0 and a simple working copy (no switched or externals directories) on Windows 7 and it seems to work although not instantly. Maybe your setup is more complicated. Also, have you tried with a clean checkout? In the end it may be worthy of a [bug report](http://tortoisesvn.net/reportbug.html).